# Android Layout not displaying properly

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout problem, the idea is that the buttons and text dont show

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#5094c5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/buton_produse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/produse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Produse"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/buton_produse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/produse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Produse"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/buton_produse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/produse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Produse"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/buton_produse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/produse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Produse"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you need to make button and textview invisible

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better try with **RelativeLayout**. This seems to be too nested and too much complicated than it suppose to be.

Comment: i have added the title part and apparently it pushes the rest to the right

Comment: Got it, my bad, the first layout was horizontal not vertical

Answer (score 0):

Set the height and width in the xml layout file to what they should be when they are visible but initially, in code, get a reference to them and make them invisible. Then, when needed, you can make them visible (in code).

Answer (score 0):

You can give `setVisibility()` property to button and `textview` in layout.